# SQLite dynamic aliases

Tags: sql, sqlite, alias

I'd like to define a dynamic alias on sqlite (in order to have the most generic SQL query I could).

I have two tables t1 & t2

t1 structure:

```
id|url|type
```

t2 structure:

```
id|us|es|fr|de|nl
```

My request is as follows:

```
SELECT t1.*,us as name FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON (t1.id = t2.id) ORDER BY t1.id ASC;
```

What I want to do, is to have an alias (eg: name) that gives me the correct value of t2.us matching the id, except if the type id 1.

Eg, I have two entries in each table:

```
id|url|type
1|http://www.google.com/|0
2|file:///tmp/file.txt|1
```

And for t2:

```
id|us|es|fr|de|nl
1|love|amar|amour|die liebe|liefde
2|sugar|azucar|sucre|zucker|suiker
```

I want to have something like this:

```
id|url|type|name
1|http://www.google.com/|0|love
2|file:///tmp/file/txt|1|file:///tmp/file/txt
```

In case of type is 0, do a research in the t2 table.
In case of type is 1, simply put the "url" field as name.

Don't really know if it's clear, and if it's possible with SQLite.
I'd like to avoid doing this programmatically (in C).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for a conditional statement to choose what column to show:

```
SELECT 
    t1.*, 
    CASE WHEN TYPE = 1 THEN url ELSE us END AS name 
FROM t1 
INNER JOIN t2 ON (t1.id = t2.id) 
ORDER BY t1.id ASC;
```

Sample output:

```
| id |                    url | type |                 name |
|----|------------------------|------|----------------------|
|  1 | http://www.google.com/ |    0 |                 love |
|  2 |   file:///tmp/file.txt |    1 | file:///tmp/file.txt |
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/2673c/1)

Comment: I forgot to ask if I can do a conditionnal JOIN. In case of the type = 1, I'd like to avoid doing the JOIN ? Because if there is only 1 entry in t2 table with id 1, the sql request will only show 1 entry, as the join will fail for (t1.id = t2.id), if id = 2.

Comment: @Lazao Not sure I understand, but try changing the `INNER JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN`